# Build binary tree structure dynamically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, binary-tree

I am working on MLM project where I want to build a tree structure(one root node and only two child nodes). I have data stored in a SQL Server database in below format:

```
rootId   child1Id   child2Id   referbyid
----------------------------------------
1        2          3           
2        4          5          1
3        6          7          1
4        8          9          2
5        10         11         1
6        12         13         3
```

and so on (these data are simple and just for example)

I tried with googleOrgChart to display the data but doesn't meet my requirement. Please find the screenshots for more understanding

**Actual**

[Result which I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWkcw.png)

**Expected**

[Result I am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA8Ce.png)

Can anybody help me display this data in binary tree format or in expected format which I have shown in the second screenshot?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The data in your database doesn't line up quite correctly and is likely causing the issue.

From what I understand the column referbyid is the parent node, rootid is the current node and the two child columns are the child nodes.

The row with the rootId of 5 has a referbyid of 1, changing this to 2 should fix your issue.

Comment: Changing referbyid from 1 to 2 for rootId 5 will fix the structure that I agree  but that doesn't solve/meet the business requirement.

So data will be in similar format and I need the chart as I shown in screenshot. 

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I find that quite interesting. I can't understand how you'd be able to interpret the data. If anything,  I'd make a shot in the dark as say the data you have is erroneous. But this is just a guess.

However, I have noticed an additional issue... where has node 7 gone in your actual result image?